# Cloud-based podcatcher?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a podcatcher that downloads and stores media to a cloud or to a third party online storage service like Dropbox?

I am looking for either a hosted service or an app that can be installed on my server and will download the podcasts I listen to and store them online.

I used to use iTunes to get the podcasts on my computer, but if I was away and my computer was off they wouldn't automatically download, and some podcasts will only let you download the last published podcast so if you miss one you are out of luck.  Now I use a podcatcher on my Droid but I'd like to have the podcasts accessible on my PC or my media center without having to manually synchronise.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at GPodder http://gpodder.org/. It stores information in the cloud (http://gpodder.net/) on which sows you have listened to and lets you install a client on your machine for downloading the content.

Comment: That looked promising however it doesn't appear that they actually save the podcast downloads on their servers.  Do you use the service?

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. Thanks anyway.